# I am trying to fetch data from IMDB and storing it in pandas.DataFrame , I am able to fetch data 1 page but not getting data for next 8-9 pages

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to fetch data from 8 IMDB pages and put it in pandas Dataframe, for that I successfully wrote a code for fetching data from page 1 but when added another for loop in my code to fetch data for more than one page then I am getting empty Dataframe, mostly last 6-7 lines of code are used for multiple pages.

```
#importing required Libraries
import pandas as pd   #to create dataframe
import requests       #to send the request to the URL
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #to get the content in the form of HTML
import numpy as np  # to count the values (in our case)

#assigning the URL with variable name url
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating'
#request allow you to send HTTP request
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating")

#creating an empty list, so that we can append the values
movie_name = []
year = []
time = []
rating = []
metascore = []
votes = []
gross = []
#Note: These three list are added recently,
description = []
Director = []
Stars = []

#storing the meaningfull required data in the variable
movie_data = soup.findAll('div', attrs= {'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

#calling one by one using for loop
for store in movie_data:
    name = store.h3.a.text
    movie_name.append(name)
    year_of_release = store.h3.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold').text.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    year.append(year_of_release)
    runtime = store.p.find('span', class_ = 'runtime').text.replace(' min', '')
    time.append(runtime)
    rate = store.find('div', class_ = 'inline-block ratings-imdb-rating').text.replace('\n', '')
    rating.append(rate)
    meta  = store.find('span', class_ = 'metascore').text.replace(' ', '') if store.find('span', class_ = 'metascore') else '^^^^^^'
    metascore.append(meta)
    #since, gross and votes have same attributes, that's why we had created a common variable and then used indexing
    value = store.find_all('span', attrs = {'name': 'nv'})
    vote = value[0].text
    votes.append(vote)
    grosses = value[1].text if len(value) >1 else '*****'
    gross.append(grosses)
    # Description of the Movies -- Not explained in the Video, But you will figure it out. 
    describe = store.find_all('p', class_ = 'text-muted')
    description_ = describe[1].text.replace('\n', '') if len(describe) >1 else '*****'
    description.append(description_)
     #Cast Details -- Scraping Director name and Stars -- Not explained in Video
    cast = store.find("p", class_ = '')
    cast = cast.text.replace('\n', '').split('|')
    cast = [x.strip() for x in cast]
    cast = [cast[i].replace(j, "") for i,j in enumerate(["Director:", "Stars:"])]
    Director.append(cast[0])
    Stars.append([x.strip() for x in cast[1].split(",")])

    #creating a dataframe using pandas library
movie_DF = pd.DataFrame({'Name of movie': movie_name, 'Year of relase': year, 'Watchtime': time, 'Movie Rating': rating,'Metascore': metascore, 'Votes':votes,"description":description,"Directors":Director,"stars":Stars})
movie_DF1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(2,9):
    response = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating,desc&count=100&start={}01&ref_=adv_nxt".format(i))
    movie_data = pd.DataFrame({'Name of movie': movie_name, 'Year of relase': year, 'Watchtime': time, 'Movie Rating': rating,'Metascore': metascore, 'Votes':votes,"description":description,"Directors":Director,"stars":Stars})
    movie_DF1.append(movie_data)  #,ignore_index = True

print(movie_DF1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with pandas but rather how to paginate the list of results.

If you look at the address bar in your browser, you can see that there's an extra parameter `start=101`, `start=201`, etc. when you navigate to a new page. We can replicate that using `requests`:

```py
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/'
params = {
    'count': 1000,
    'groups': 'top_1000',
    'sort': 'user_rating'
}

pages = []
for i in range(10):
    params['start'] = (i * 100) + 1
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    r.raise_for_status()
    pages.append(r.text)

# Now parse the HTML pages
for page in pages:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    ...
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with ML, either.